# Can not "redirect after login" to page that is the target of a link

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a page called **Member** and a Page called **Dashboard** in my DNN 8 site. The "Page" **Dashboard** is not a page but rather is just a "link" to the member page

as seen here: 
[image]

Now when I go to **site settings -> user account settings -> login settings** and try to assign the **Member** or **Dashboard** page as the target for the "redirect to after login", It won't let me choose the Member page and the dashboard page does not even appear in the list.  *(The dashboard page is shown in the page management admin section)*

Why is this an can someone help me set either of these pages as the redirect target after login.

Comment: That pages are available for guest users? (I mean not logged in users)

Comment: One thing you might try is making DASHBOARD a page, see if it becomes selectable, then go back and change it back to a Link.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Mehdi, the page did not have view permissions for registered users.  Once I fixed that I was able to assign the member page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out I had a permission conflict.  I set the registred users as not able to see the page but gave access to a new role I created.  Once I allowed registered users to view page I could select it in the redirect after login.  silly thing to miss